# Submitting a from, processed from ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

```
<head>
<script>
function showit(str) {
      if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","showuser.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
    }       
}
</script>
<head>
<body>
<button onclick='showit(1)'>First User</button>
<button onclick='showit(2)'>Second User</button>
<button onclick='showit(3)'>Third User</button>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

?>
<div id="txtHint">
</div>
</body>
```

This is the main page, when I Click the button, It processes Ajax request to `showuser.php` and bring me a form.
**SHOWUSER.PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $id=$_GET['q'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","application");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='delete'>Delete</td><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='update' checked>Update</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>ID:<td><input type='text' name='id' value='".$row[id]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Name:<td><input type='text' name='uname' value='".$row[uname]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Store:<td><input type='text' value='".$row[store]."' disabled></td><td>";
        echo "<select name='store'>";
        $displaystore=new admin();
        $displaystore->storeoption();
        echo"</select>";
        echo "</td></tr><tr><td>Date:<td><input type='text' name='date' value='".$row[date]."'></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td></form>";     
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

It displays The Form, but when i click, it doesn't work!! That is when I click submit button from the form, nothing happens!!!
Anybody Can Help? Thank You In Advance.

Comment: You are missing action attribute in your form tag. Add a url to the action like `action="test.php"`

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: Naaa!!! I have tied it!! Still same result

Comment: @Jay The question says that the AJAX works and the form is displayed.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I think he is saying that the javascript runs and the new Table containing the new form displays but then the submit button in the new piece of HTML does not work

Comment: Ah, I misread @Keerthi

Comment: Yes the form is displayed but the submit don't work! Even The page didn't load for submit!!

Comment: When you press the submit button it will rerun `mainform.php` but you have no code in there that does anything when that happens.

Comment: Even if had code, from my index.php it doesnt do any action!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think @PierreDuc had the right idea.

First I fixed the index.php to properly terminate the PHP `if` statement and the javascript to properly close the curly brackets

```
<head>
<script>
function showit(str) {
      if (str.length==0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }
      var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("GET","showuser.php?q="+str,true);
      xmlhttp.send();
 }       
//}                                               <-- fix1
</script>
<head>
<body>
<button onclick='showit(1)'>First User</button>
<button onclick='showit(2)'>Second User</button>
<button onclick='showit(3)'>Third User</button>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

}                                                  <-- fix2
?>
<div id="txtHint">
</div>
</body>
```

Then this script ran without errors

Then I moved the `<form>` .... `</form>` outside the `<table>` ... `</table>` and it all worked.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $id=$_GET['q'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","application");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    echo "<form method='post'>";                       <-- fix3

    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='delete'>Delete</td><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='update' checked>Update</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>ID:<td><input type='text' name='id' value='".$row[id]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Name:<td><input type='text' name='uname' value='".$row[uname]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Store:<td><input type='text' value='".$row[store]."' disabled></td><td>";
        echo "<select name='store'>";
        $displaystore=new admin();
        $displaystore->storeoption();
        echo"</select>";
        echo "</td></tr><tr><td>Date:<td><input type='text' name='date' value='".$row[date]."'></td></tr>";
        <-- next line...removed </form> added </tr>
        echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td></tr>";  
    }
    echo "</table></form>";                            <-- fix4
}
?>
```

and then the new form's submit button worked

Answer (score 1):

A form inside a table. That seems to be a bad thing. But I believe it is not working, because the form is missing an action

`<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: Adding action  also has the same output

Comment: Problem was basically putting a `<form>` inside `<table>` if you miss out the `action=` it just runs the script that built this form again. But as someone upvoted my answer I thought I should share that with you as you got there first, all I did was prove it by testing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything with the post data, on this line

```
echo "<form method='post'>";
```

You're telling the form to post to itself. Add an action attribute, or add some additional code, to process the data, like so:

```
<?php
if($_POST) { print_r($_POST); }

if(isset($_GET['q'])){
    $id=$_GET['q'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","application");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<form method='post'>";
        echo "<tr><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='delete'>Delete</td><td><input type='radio' name='status' value='update' checked>Update</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>ID:<td><input type='text' name='id' value='".$row[id]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Name:<td><input type='text' name='uname' value='".$row[uname]."'></td></tr><tr><td>Store:<td><input type='text' value='".$row[store]."' disabled></td><td>";
        echo "<select name='store'>";
        $displaystore=new admin();
        $displaystore->storeoption();
        echo"</select>";
        echo "</td></tr><tr><td>Date:<td><input type='text' name='date' value='".$row[date]."'></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></td></form>";     
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

All this will do is show you the post data, but you can insert it into the database as required.

Another thing, you are grabbing an unfiltered $_GET variable, here `$id=$_GET['q'];` could cause some security problems. Have a look into escaping that input, or using prepared statements.

Comment: Everything work fine, when i go showuser.php?q=1 and run the form, but nothing happens in index.php from the AJAX request!!!

Answer (score 0):

You might try logging the readystate on the client side and checking the server side logs.

```js
function showit(str) {
  if (str.length == 0) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var txtHint = document.getElementById("txtHint");
  var rState = document.getElementById("rState");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    rState.innerHTML += "readyState: " + xmlhttp.readyState + ", status: " + xmlhttp.status + ", responseText: " + xmlhttp.responseText + "\n";
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      txtHint.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.onerror = function() {
    var html = "<b>ERROR</b>\n"
    for (var k in xmlhttp) {
      if (xmlhttp[k] && typeof xmlhttp[k] !== "function") {
        html += k + ": " + xmlhttp[k] + "\n";
      }
    }
    rState.innerHTML += html;
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "showuser.php?q=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='showit(1)'>First User</button>
<button onclick='showit(2)'>Second User</button>
<button onclick='showit(3)'>Third User</button>
<div id="txtHint"></div>
<pre id="rState">
<h2>ready state log</h2>
</pre>
```